# react native Generated app-debug.apk file working in android emulator but not working in physical mobile device

Tags: react-native, apk, react-native-keychain

I have created app-debug.apk file successfully from the following command :

```
native bundle command (full command) 
./gradlew assembleDebug.
```

This debug.apk is not working in mobile device after installation.
on click on app in mobile, its showing only white screen. but perfectly working in emulator.

These are the following package that I am using.

```
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.9.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.22.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.5",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
```

I have also added the following in android/app/build.gradle

```
`apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
 implementation project(':react-native-keychain') --> at dependencies block
```

`
following are the setting.gradle file changes

```
rootProject.name = 'projectName'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-keychain'
project(':react-native-keychain').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-keychain/android')
```

Could you please help me? How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: what does ```adb logcat``` shows?

Comment: I have tried to execute logcat command on device, there are many logs, havent found any exception.